# Newly installed Graphics card not detected

Tags: graphics, video

I have a clean install of Ubuntu 22.04. I can't figure out if I'm actually using my dedicated graphics card. When I connect the monitor to the graphics card output, it doesn't show anything, the monitor doesn't even recognize a signal. But when I plug it into the motherboard connector, everything works more or less fine (I get a non-native default resolution, but I fixed it temporarily with xrandr, which may not be related to my question). And the strangest thing is that while connected to the motherboard, the EVGA software tells me that I'm using the dedicated card, and the `inxi -G` command in the terminal does too. Is it possible to use the graphics card if the monitor is not connected to it? Am I being cheated by the system? Am I being silly (I'm probably a Linux newbie)? Most importantly, how do I fix the output issue: I want to connect it to the card just to be sure? System details along with any attached command output (e.g. snapshots).

Comment: Is my new Graphic card (https://www.allhdd.com/evga-12g-p4-2992-kr-graphics-card/) compatible with Ubuntu because it is working fine with the motherboard connector?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Silly question, but have you installed the nvidia drivers, yet?

Comment: No, you have to connect your display to the GPU if you want to use it as your display adapter. Did you install Ubuntu before you installed the GPU? If so, I suggest you reinstall. Make sure your system has all of the internal components you plan to use *before* you install Ubuntu. Installing Nvidia drivers after system installation is sometimes challenging. But you can try `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` as this utility should take care of it for you. If it doesn't, reinstall Ubuntu and make sure to select "download updates" and "install 3rd party drivers" when it asks.

Comment: Sounds from this, https://superuser.com/q/1751189/122808, like it's not working under Windows either. AFAIK, Quadro FX1800 needs Nvidia-340 drivers, it's a 14y old card.

Comment: @pbhj No, it's a Titan Z and should work with 470 drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Change in BIOS to dedicated graphics.

Checks the currents from the power supply to the graphics. If everything is ok, make a flash drive with ubuntu and try to run the system without installing it.
Download the correct drivers and install to check if the graphics is in good condition.

For me it's a problem of lack of power from the power supply if you check all the things before.

I'm also new to linux